# Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Tags: c

Есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int b() {
    int *b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 11;
    return b;
} 

int main() {
    int *a = b();
    *a = 13;
    printf("%i\n", *a);
}
```

Как из функции main() поменять значение в памяти, инициализированной в функции b()?

Comment: `int *b() {` *(3 символа нужно...)*

Comment: Для начала - следить за диагностическими сообщениями компилятора. Компилятор ясно указал вам на вашу ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* b() {
    int *b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    //       ^^^^^ это приведение в C не требуется 
    *b = 11;
    return b;
} 

int main() {
    int *a = b();
    *a = 13;
    printf("%i\n", *a);
}
```